# Supabase onAuthStateChange not firing after google / github login or magic link

Tags: reactjs, supabase

I am using Google login from Supabase integration. It was working fine before but now I don't understand why not working.

I didn't change something but after select account and redirect to page adding session to storage not working. It stuck on page with access_token url. Token is also valid and when i decoded in JWT io it shows data. So the only problem  supabase.auth.onAuthStateChange method is not triggering in App.tsx.

I also asked same question in discuession of Supabase:

I have google login in my React (vite) application. There is no special configuration and it was working before. But now I after redirect from google to application I have access token and other fields in url but session is not setting to browser storage.

version of package :     "@supabase/supabase-js": "^2.26.0",

using this method : signInWithOAuth

[image]

I also saw this in Supabase Auth logs ;: GOTRUE_JWT_ADMIN_GROUP_NAME not supported by Supabase's GoTrue, will be removed soon

On App.jsx I am checking like this:

[image]

I tried login supabase and expecting works without issue.

Comment: Pls don’t post images of code. Pls read: [Why shouldn’t I post images of code?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-should-i-not-upload-images-of-code-data-errors#:~:text=You%20should%20not%20post%20code,for%20users%20with%20visual%20impairments.)